# Why Java uses so much memory with JTextArea having some text

Tags: java, memory, jtextarea, arabic

I am have a simple application with only one `JTextArea` and two buttons. Initially when Application is loaded it is using about **28MB** of memory. When set the String (having Arabic letters, string length 5000) to the JTextArea It is showing that Memory usage is **270MB** and not freeing that (much for this App, I noted that NetBeans is using less than that). I am not opening any file that is using that memory.
What can be the possible reason and how I can reduce the memory usage?

**Note**: Memory usage is from Task manager.

### Edit:

```
public class FileReadTest extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Jbutton readButton;
    public FileReadTest() {
        initialize();
    }
 
    private void initialize() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setTitle("File Reader Test");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.Plain, 18))
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        readButton=new JButton("ReadFrom File");
        readButton.addActionListiner(new AvtionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
          FileReader reader=null;
          try {
            //
            // Read some text from file to display in
            // the JTextArea.
            //
            reader=new FileReader("myfile.txt");
            textArea.read(, null);
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
            try{
              reader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
          }
         }
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FileReadTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
       }
    }
```

Case is same if I press `read` button or manually copy and paste the text.

Comment: That seems very excessive.  Have you tried to use jvisualvm to see the actual memory usage.  My only thoughts are 1) problem with the installed fonts on the system 2) some event handler on the text area doing something repeatedly.

Comment: using Times New Roman font, no event handling on text area.

Comment: Please do not take the value displayed in the task manager but use a tool like JVisualVM to determine the amount memory used. Also you can try to set the maximum limit of memory used to some smaller value (`-Xmx128m` for example).

Comment: @aquestion - He means an SSCCE ... so that other people can run your code and understand what it is doing.